# Inline handler not being called in IE9 for select element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out what could be causing a problem in IE9 on a production machine. We have a `<select>` combo box with an inline change handler (I'm aware that's bad practice but I can't do anything about that at the moment) that is not getting called.

The HTML looks like the following (copied from dev tools)

```
<select name="propertyName" id="propertyName" onchange="Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._field_OnChange();">
  <option value="Property_103156" title="Boolean Prop" selected="selected">Boolean Prop</option>
  <option value="Property_103072" title="String Prop A">String Prop A</option>
</select>
```

While on a webex with the customer, I put a breakpoint in `Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._field_OnChange()` and it was not being called (in IE9).  If I call it manually from the console, everything works.

We went to the exact same machine with IE8 and `Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._field_OnChange()` was being called and everything was working correctly.

The only other information that I think may be relevant is the fact that the dropdown is created dynamically.

Anybody run across something similar? Any suggestions on what to try? Maybe some setting in IE that can break this spell?

**Creation of HTML**

The select is being added to the page with the following code. The HTML to be inserted looks like

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <ul id="setStateConditions">
        <li class="setStateLabel">Property Name</li>
        <li class="setStateContent">
            <select name='propertyName' id='propertyName'  onchange='Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._field_OnChange();' >
<option value='Property_103156' title='Boolean Prop'  selected='selected' >Boolean Prop</option>
<option value='Property_103072' title='String Prop A' >String Prop A</option>
</select>
<br />
<input id="filterExpression" name="filterExpression" type="hidden" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    _condition_strings = 
    {
        "equal": "Is Equal To",
        "not_equal": "Is Not Equal To",
        "contains": "Contains",
        "less_than": "Is Less Than",
        "less_than_or_equal": "Is Less Than or Equal To",
        "greater_than": "Is Greater Than",
        "greater_than_or_equal": "Is Greater Than or Equal To",
        "literal": "Literal Value",
        "is_collected": "Has Been Collected",
        "is_not_collected": "Has Not Been Collected"
    }; 


    function getLeftUrl(leftMenu, value) {
        var selectedProperty = $('#propertyName').val() || '';

        return "/Property/ReflectionMenuLeftByRelation/" + workflow.data_provider_id
             + "?relationSafeName=" + selectedProperty 
             + "&nameWithParents=" + value; 
    };

    function getRightUrl(rightMenu, value) {
        //Find value of left to filter 
        var selectedProperty = $('#propertyName').val() || '';
        var leftMenuValue = rightMenu.item.prevAll(".left-operand").eq(0).attr("value") || '';

        return "/Property/ReflectionMenuRightByRelation/" + workflow.data_provider_id
             + "?relationSafeName=" + selectedProperty
             + "&nameWithParents=" + value
             + "&compatableWithSafeName=" + leftMenuValue; 
    };

    function getOperatorUrl(operatorMenu, value) {
        //Find value of left in order to get the correct list of 

        var selectedProperty = $('#propertyName').val() || '';
        var leftMenuValue = operatorMenu.item.prevAll(".left-operand").eq(0).attr("value") || '';

        return "/Property/OperatorsByRelation/" + workflow.data_provider_id
             + "?relationSafeName=" + selectedProperty
             + "&compatableWithSafeName=" + leftMenuValue; 
    };

    function getLiteralControlUrl(rightMenu, startValue, leftMenuValue, uniqueRowCounter) {
        var selectedProperty = $('#propertyName').val();
        var leftMenuValue = leftMenuValue || rightMenu.item.prevAll(".left-operand").eq(0).attr("value") || '';

        return "/Property/PropertyValueByRelation/" + workflow.data_provider_id
             + "?relationSafeName=" + selectedProperty
             + "&safeNameWithParents=" + leftMenuValue
             + "&domId=literal_" + uniqueRowCounter
             + "&startValue=" + startValue; 
    }

    function getDereferenceUrl(menu){
        var selectedProperty = $('#propertyName').val() || '';

        return "/Property/ResolveSafeNameToDisplayNameByRelation/" + workflow.data_provider_id
             + "?relationSafeName=" + selectedProperty
             + "&safeNameWithParents=" + menu.getValue();
    }






    $(function() {
        ExpBuilder.init($("#filterExpression").val());

        //Move to a wider space
        $("#expressionBuilder").appendTo("#propertyValueWide");
    });

onSaveParameters = function() {
    //When User clicks save
    if ($("#expressionBuilder").is(":visible")) {
        //TODO check for empties    
        $("#filterExpression").val(ExpBuilder.getJson())
        Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._UpdateJson()
    }
}

ExpBuilder.errorNoCondition = 'There are no conditions.';

</script>

<div id="expressionBuilder" style="display:none;">
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div class="condLoader"></div>
    <div class="condWrapper" style="display:none;">
        <div class="conditionGroup condTier1 condTop" >
            <div class="conditionGroupBullet"><div><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="10" height="3"></div></div>
            <div class="conditionHead">
                <div class="conditionOperation">
                    <select id="100" name="anyAll">
                        <option value="or">Any</option>
                        <option value="and">All</option>
                    </select> 
                </div>
                <div class="closeBtn"><img src="/images/buttons/close.png" class="closeGroupImg" alt=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="conditionContent"></div>

            <ul class="buttons buttonsLeft">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="btnAddCondition"><span>Create Condition</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="btnAddConditionGroup"><span>Create Group Condition</span></a>
                </li>                
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <ul class="buttons buttonsLeft hidden">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="btnAddCondition" onclick="CreateJsonBase();return false;"><span>Create Json</span></a>
        </li>       
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="btnAddCondition" onclick="ExpBuilder.LoadData();return false;"><span>Load Json</span></a>
        </li>                     
    </ul>

    <!-- Template for Conditions -->
    <div class="condition hidden">
        <div class="conditionBullet"><div><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="10" height="3"></div></div>
        <div class="conditionItem">

            <a href="#" class="left-operand"></a> 
            <a href="#" class="operator"></a> 
            <a href="#" class="right-operand"></a>
            <span class="right-literal"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="closeBtn"><img src="/images/buttons/close.png" class="closeImg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<span id="propertyValue">
    <input type="checkbox" id="setDefault" onclick="Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._field_OnChange();" />
    <label for="setDefault">Default Value</label>

    <span id="defaultOptions"> 
        <input id="setPropertyValue" name="setPropertyValue" onblur="Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._UpdateJson();" onchange="Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._UpdateJson();" onkeypress="Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._UpdateJson();" type="text" value="" /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="allowEdit" onclick="Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._field_OnChange();" />
        <label for="allowEdit">Allow Edit</label> <br />
    </span>
</span>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="isRequired" onclick="Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._field_OnChange();" checked/> 
    <label for="isRequired">Is Required</label>
</div>
<input type="text" id="PropertyName" class="hidden" />


        </li>
    </ul>


    <div id="propertyValueWide"></div>


    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

And it's added to the page using (where `htmlString` contains the HTML I've shown above)

```
$(htmlString).appendTo('.settings-form');
```

Comment: If it’s created dynamically, and you can change the code that creates it dynamically, you can do something about that bad practice.

Comment: @minitech No I can't, the server is sending back HTML/JavaScript. The only way to do it would be to apply a hotfix which is not really an option

Comment: How is it being created dynamically? Is it via `.innerHTML`, or `document.createElement()` with `setAttribute()`? I don't know if it makes a difference. Just curious.

Comment: @cookiemonster digging to find out exactly...

Comment: Is there an error in the console suggesting `Workflows.CoreSetPropertyActivity._field_OnChange()` is undefined? It feels like a race condition since you can call it manually via the console later and everything works. Where on the page is the script included?

Comment: @clav The function definitely exists before I insert the dynamic HTML, otherwise, I would be seeing an error on the console. Also, I can wait as long as I want after the dropdown is loaded and still no go...

Comment: @clav It is done using `$(htmlString).appendTo('.settings-form');` I've added this information to the question

Comment: So you're unable to create a minimal example that replicates the issue?

Comment: When you were testing did you tab away from the select field after changing the value or just change the value? It seems some versions of IE require the field to lose focus before `onchange` actually fires, see: http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/scott_leberknight/2005/04/onclick_versus_onchange_in_ie_and_firefox

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes, I'm unable to recreate it. We've tried to emulate the customer's environment locally as much as possible (data dump + IE9) and we cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @clav That is a good guess, but I've tried changing the focus to the other field that is displayed and still have the problem. I guess maybe I can try that again with the customer to be 100% sure

Comment: Did you verify whether or not the handler function is being created on the element's `.onchange` property?

Comment: @cookiemonster No I didn't, I was under the impression that `elem.onchange` was independent from the `onchange` attribute. I'll make sure to try your suggestion and clav's on our next webex. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the the problem is that the customer was running [IE9 with the release to manufacturing version (RTM)](http://microsoft-news.com/internet-explorer-9-rtm-download/) which is a pre-release of Internet Explorer just before the GA release.

The customer installed IE9 on a different machine and the problem is gone. I'm pretty confident that it will be fixed when they reinstall IE on that machine.

Thanks everyone for pitching in.